# PHP DateTime cannot parse 31/05/2018

Tags: php, datetime

I've got DateTime running inside a foreach loop that is parsing a midata.csv file, and in one column there is a date string.

It runs though a good chunk of them until it gets to "31/05/2018", where it produces the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (31/05/2018) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character`

I'm just passing the string normally like so:
`$date = new DateTime($row[0]);`

Why is this date causing a problem?

Comment: Can you put that string through `bin2hex()` and show us?

Comment: Using `/` will be taken as m/d/y format, if you have `-` it will be d/m/y.

Comment: when using `/` DateTime seems to expect m/d/y. `new DateTime("05/31/2018");` is working, as is  `new DateTime("31.05.2018");`

Comment: Apply the format `$date = (new DateTime())->createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/05/2018');`

Comment: You're really going to want to use `DateTime::createFromFormat`. Month/Day/Year is a non-standard format, and PHP's going to have to guess at which variant you're using if you give it something like `05/05/2018`.

Comment:  Yes, but according to the error it doesn’t even seem to get to the “/“ part…

Comment: @deceze I think it's just a not well formulated error-message (that might be bubbling up from somewhere in the parsing)

Comment: @deceze I'm getting the same error on `$date = new DateTime('31/05/2018');`.

Comment: Mmmkay, typically helpful PHP error message. 